# Why is RStudio displaying UTF-8 characters as <U+0421> in viewer

Tags: r, rstudio

Windows 10
R 3.4.3
RStudio 1.0.153

I am using the tidyverse library to read in a tab delimited file which is UTF-8 encoded and which contains Cyrillic characters.  This file displays fine when using Sublime text.

After I import the file using read_delim and View() the data frame, all columns containing Cyrillic characters display them similar to this:

...

Read in using

```
SFDE_All_Contacts20171220 <- read_delim("C:/Users/tporter/Downloads/SFDE - All Contacts20171220.txt",
"\t", escape_double = FALSE, locale = locale(),trim_ws = TRUE)
```

I have not set a locale.

How do I display Cyrillic in the Viewer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Solution Found:

```
 Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "russian")
```

See https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-and-foreign-characters/